# How can I sign all executable cmake targets to enable core dumps on MacOS?

Tags: macos, cmake, digital-signature

According to [this](https://nasa.github.io/trick/howto_guides/How-to-dump-core-file-on-MacOS.html), MacOS executables have to be signed in order to produces core dumps.

The suggested procedure is:

> For an executable to dump a core-file it must be signed. To do this, create an `.entitlements` file with the com.apple.security.get-task-allow entitlement set:
>
> `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :com.apple.security.get-task-allow bool true" segv.entitlements`
>
> Using this `.entitlements` file, sign the executable:
>
> `codesign -s - -f --entitlements segv.entitlements segv`

We have a hierarchical structure of `CMakeLists.txt` files, with libraries and executables targets in subdirectories.

Is there a way to have CMake automatically sign all the included sub-targets (when run on MacOS) without, or with only minimal, changes to the sub-targets?

The generated `segv.entitlements` file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.get-task-allow</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

So I could add it to the repository, which only leaves the `codesign` step.

Note: We are not building from XCode, but rather using different IDEs (CLion, VSCode, etc) with CMake.  The production executables will be running on Linux, MacOS is just for development.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the `PlistBuddy` command during CMake's configure phase with its [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) command.

Then use [the build-events signature of `add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events) to define a `POST_BUILD` custom command on each target that runs the signing command.

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe it would look something like this:

```
set(entitlements_file "${CMAKE_BUILD_DIR}/foo.entitlements")

execute_process(COMMAND /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :com.apple.security.get-task-allow bool true" "${entitlements_file}")

set(targets_to_sign target_a target_b target_c)
foreach(target "${targets_to_sign}")
    add_custom_command(TARGET "${target}" POST_BUILD
    COMMAND codesign -s - -f --entitlements "${entitlements_file}" "$<TARGET_FILE:${target}>"
    COMMENT "sign target \"${target}\" to enable core dump on MacOS"
    VERBATIM
)
endforeach()
```